# The sessions are dying on redirect

Tags: laravel

The sessions are no longer working on redirect, if i set a session with `session([ 'key' => 'value' ]);` is working on the same page, but if i set the session in controller, after redirect is NULL, also, when i redirect, the values passed `->with(array)` are NULL:

```
return redirect()->route('account.login', ['subdomain' => 'account'])->with(
[
    'request-tfa' => true,
    'requested-email' => $validatedData['email'],
    'requested-password' => encrypt($validatedData['password'])
]);
```

When i get the value using `Session::get('request-tfa')` is NULL, until now, this worked perfectly.

Do anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Should i try to use a database as session storage? but i don't know how to setup the database to store the sessions.

**EDIT:** I changed the session driver to database and is still not working, but the sessions are stored.

And even \Auth::attempt is not working, like, if i use:

```
if(\Auth::attempt(['email' => $validatedData['email'], 'password' => $validatedData['password']]))
{
    return \Auth::id();
}
```

it working, but if i have `return redirect` i am guest again.

**EDIT X2** 
Well, i changed my virtual host domain and restarted my pc and now is working...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a session after redirect you should use:

```
session()->put('something')
```

Comment: is the same as session([ 'key' => 'value' ]) and i tried and with ->put and is not working